# Implicit declaration of scandir; alphasort is undeclared

Tags: c, c99, scandir

I am trying to use `scandir` to print a list of files in the current directory. When I try to compile, I am receiving the following errors and warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scandir’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
error: ‘alphasort’ undeclared (first use in this function)
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I am including `<dirent.h>`, which to my knowledge should define `scandir()` and all related functions. And I don't see any errors in my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
...
int printFiles(){
    struct dirent **nameList;
    int numOfFiles = scandir(".", &nameList, 0, alphasort);

    //TODO print file names
    return numOfFiles;
}
....
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm compiling using `gcc` with the `-c99` flag.

Am I simply overlooking something? I can't figure out why it's failing to compile.

Comment: The reason for the different messages is that the compiler knows from context that `scandir()` must be a function, but it cannot tell from the context that `alphasort()` is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `-std=c99`, only functions that are strictly a part of the C99 standard are included by the header files. `scandir()` is not in the C99 standard. Therefore, you have to set a preprocessor variable to ensure that the function prototype is included. For example, the man page for `scandir()` indicates that setting the `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE` preprocessor variables before you do the `#include` will fix the problem. Or, you can use `#define _GNU_SOURCE` which will in turn set quite a few different variables for you (including `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE`).

Your code will still compile with the warning and work because C allows you to compile with implicitly defined functions, and the linker will correctly link the call to `scandir()` to the proper function.

Comment: Thank you, adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` fixed my problems.

Comment: These functions are also in POSIX, so `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` would work reasonably well too.

Answer (score 1):

what macro you use is decided by the macro in dirent.h on your own computer.usually it located in /usr/include/dirent.h.

1. find scandir in dirent.h ,you will find the macro which make scandir Invisible.for example in my conmputer,it is "__USE_BSD ,__USE_MISC".

   ```
   #if defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_MISC
   /* Return the file descriptor used by DIRP.  */
   extern int dirfd (DIR *__dirp) __THROW __nonnull ((1));

   # if defined __OPTIMIZE__ && defined _DIR_dirfd
   #  define dirfd(dirp)   _DIR_dirfd (dirp)
   # endif

   # ifndef MAXNAMLEN
   /* Get the definitions of the POSIX.1 limits.  */
   #  include <bits/posix1_lim.h>

   /* `MAXNAMLEN' is the BSD name for what POSIX calls `NAME_MAX'.  */
   #  ifdef NAME_MAX
   #   define MAXNAMLEN    NAME_MAX
   #  else
   #   define MAXNAMLEN    255
   #  endif
   # endif

   # define __need_size_t
   # include <stddef.h>

   # ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
   extern int scandir (__const char *__restrict __dir,
       struct dirent ***__restrict __namelist,
       int (*__selector) (__const struct dirent *),
       int (*__cmp) (__const void *, __const void *))
   __nonnull ((1, 2));
   # else
   #  ifdef __REDIRECT
   extern int __REDIRECT (scandir,
       (__const char *__restrict __dir,
       struct dirent ***__restrict __namelist,
       int (*__selector) (__const struct dirent *),
       int (*__cmp) (__const void *, __const void *)),
       scandir64) __nonnull ((1, 2));
   #  else
   #  define scandir scandir64
   #  endif
   # endif
   ```

   you know what to do now? don't be worry!it not a nice way to #define this macro directly.
2. open file features.h(located /usr/include/features.h),search "__USE_MISC" inside,you can see codes below:

   ```
   #if defined _BSD_SOURCE || defined _SVID_SOURCE
   # define __USE_MISC 1
   #endif
   ```

   it tells that if"_BSD_SOURCE "or"_SVID_SOURCE"is defined,then __USE_MISC would be defined auto.
3. consider Compatibility of you own codes,add statement below(any one or both) at start(before any statement like #include <*.h>||"*.h") of you file which will use scandir().

   ```
   #define _BSD_SOURCE  1
   #define _SVID_SOURCE 1
   ```
4. save your file and make.

Answer (score 0):

try to `#include <sys/dir.h>` file to use scandir and define `extern int alphasort(const void*,const void*);` or `extern int alphasort();` above your `printFiles`

also - you should link you program with standard library (hope it is already done)

Comment: I left out some of my includes, but I was using `<sys/dir.h>` `<stdio.h>` `<stdlib.h>` and a few others. There are several others that pertain to other specific functions. 

I also tried putting in the defines you suggested and they didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bluedanes check sys/dir.h is alphasort is declared here?

Comment: `sys/dir.h` isn't in MinGW.